# Unity - get all Collisions without OnCollisionStay

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have a sphere player and I want him to jump in direction based on all points where it touches something else.

When I jump, I want to detect all contact points (I can get them from collisions), but I don't know, how to get all collisions outside of OnCollisionStay.

I want to get all active collisions when I jump.

Answer (score 0):

Never test before

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetCollision : MonoBehaviour {
// The active collider
public Collider[] activeCollider;
// Key to jump
public KeyCode jumpKey;

void Update(){
     //Detect if jump key being pressed
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey)){
          //Get all the collider in the scene
          Collider[] allColliderInScene = FindObjectsOfType<Collider>();
          //Getting all active collider
          foreach (Collider collider in allColliderInScene){
               //Counter
               int count = 0;
               if (collider.isActiveAndEnable == true){
                    activeCollider[count] = collider;
                    count++;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

I hope it work.

Comment: It would not do what I needed, because I needed contact points to get direction of jump. You can get contact points from collision, but not collider.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way:

```
private Dictionary<string, Collision> activeCollisions = new Dictionary<string, Collision>();

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    activeCollisions[collision.collider.name] = collision;
}

private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    activeCollisions[collision.collider.name] = collision;
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    activeCollisions.Remove(collision.collider.name);
}
```

And you have a dictionary with all active collisions. I first tried it without OnCollisionStay, but there were bugs, so I added it. (I thought the collision object would not change, without OnCollisionStay sometimes there was null instead of collision)

This is not the best solution, because you have to change it on every physics tick. (And you can't have multiple collisions with one collider, if it were non-convex)

I still ask you for better answers. (Get all active collisions or contact points at one time.)